# How to add a BrandingText using Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

Some installers (built with Inno Setup) include a branding text at the bottom (see Image).
It is called BrandingText in NSIS but I couldn't find a way to do it in Inno Setup.

[image]

How can I add something like that?